# Aligning a div inside a table cell not taking effect while coverting html to pdf using mpdf

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I am using mpdf to convert my html to pdf. A fragment of the html code is like so:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id = "company_address">
            <div id="div1">

            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="div2" style="margin-left: 13.2mm; width: 100%;"> 
                <address>

                </address>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="student_address">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I view the html on the browser, div2 is properly align i.e 13.2mm away from the left of the cell but once is converted using mpdf, the aligning does not take effect, i.e all text is just close to the cell border.

Doing something like `#company_address { padding-left: 13.2mm }` works, but I don't want to go that way because I want only div2 in the cell to be aligned. Appreciate any help